# Airflow task fails to invoke lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, airflow, boto3

We have a Airflow DAG that triggers a lambda for some data processing but we are experiencing an issue with the task failing due to rate exceed error from the lambda.  It is not a concurrency issue as our quota is set at the default of 1000 and there are not any other lambdas being triggered at this specific time.  The error we are getting consistently is

```
An error occurred (TooManyRequestsException) when calling the Invoke operation (reached max retries: 4): Rate Exceeded.
[2023-07-03, 12:28:25 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1345} INFO - Marking task as FAILED. dag_id=xxxxxxxxxx, task_id=xxxxxxxxxx, execution_date=20230703T122605, start_date=20230703T122714, end_date=20230703T122825
```

This seems to indicate something with how boto3 is making the call to the AWS API as opposed to the lambda itself, but can't find anything that looks off.

Has anyone experienced rate issues while trigger lambdas?

Comment: can you share some code ? 10x

Comment: How many functions reside in your AWS account? are you sharing this account with other stakeholders in the organization? Are they sharing the same region with you?

Comment: @AllanChua this account is not shared and there are around 250 functions but they are not related to data pipeline work and are not being invoked at the same time this is.  No matter if the DAG is triggered based on its schedule or manually ad-hoc at random times it fails with rate exceed but will randomly execute successfully sometime with no pattern to the madness

Comment: @odonnry, does your AWS lambda connect to other integration points like 3rd party APIs or other AWS services?

Comment: @AllanChua The lambda triggers an ephemeral EMR cluster

Comment: Can you try to check what's happening between the functions and the EMR cluster? maybe the errors were originating from that integration.